# Finding the index to a non-specified character

Tags: javascript

Let's say for example I have a string

```
thisIsThisTuesday Day
```

I want to find the index of all the capital letters, test if there is a space before it, and if not insert one.  I would need the index of each one. 
At least from what I can see `indexOf(String)` will only produce the index of the first occurance of the character `T/t`

This :

```
for(i=0;i<str.length;i++){
  let char=str[i];

  if(isNaN(char*1)&&char==char.toUpperCase()){
    y=str.indexOf(char);
    console.log(char,y)
  }
}
```

would produce the capital letters, and their indexes but will only display the first occurrence of the character in question. I feel pretty confident that the part I am missing is a for() loop in order to move the index iteration..but it escapes me.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe not a direct dupe but you can probably use the approach that answers the following question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055152/finding-uppercase-characters-within-a-string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding uppercase characters within a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055152/finding-uppercase-characters-within-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the `String.indexOf` function can take a second argument, specifying the character it should start searching from. Take a look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

But, if you just want to find all capital letters and prefix them with a space character, if one is not found, there are many approaches, for example:

```
var str = "thisIsThisTuesday Day";
var ret = '';
for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
    if (str.substr(i, 1) == str.substr(i, 1).toUpperCase()) {
        if ((i > 0) && (str.substr(i - 1,1) != " "))
            ret += " ";
    }
    ret += str.substr(i,1);
}
```

After running this, ret will hold the value "this Is This Tuesday  Day"

Comment: please use MDN for JS documentation references.

Comment: Thank you.. this was what I was seeking originally.  I appreciate the hand !

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex:

It matches any non-whitespace character followed by a capital letter and replaces it by the two characters with a space between.

```js
const str = "thisIsThisTuesday Day";
const newstr = str.replace(/([^ ])([A-Z])/g, "$1 $2");
console.log(newstr);
```

Comment: It would be cleaner to use groups and group references (`$1`) in your replacement.

Comment: Yes but I wasn't sure about that, you can edit my answer if you want to

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regular expression:

`/(?<=\S)(?=[A-Z])/g`

The `replace` will insert spaced between characters which are non-space followed by a capital letter.

See example below:

```js
let str = "thisIsThisTuesday Day";
const res = str.replace(/(?<=\S)(?=[A-Z])/g, ' ');

console.log(res);
```

**Note:** As pointed out `?<=` (positive lookbehind) is currently not be available in all browsers.

Comment: Yup , sorry about not looking into the regex. ywc

Comment: NB: lookbehind assertions are ES2018, and not universally supported yet.

Comment: @georg ah, yes. Thanks for pointing this out. I've edited my answer

Comment: Regex has always been an achilles heal for me.  But ultimately is much more efficient I believe..   and I think now that you have been so kind as to point that out so blatently for me.( in a good way) I really need to hone that skill a bit further..

Comment: Thank you all for your time and effort in assisting with this  !

Comment: @BrBearOFS no worries, I don’t claim to be an expert in regex either, I just know a few basics because it is an incredibly powerful tool, and having the basics can allow you to do complex things like this rather easily. All it takes is a little bit of practice :)

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the string and check if each character is a capital. Something like this:

```js
const s = 'thisIsThisTuesday Day';

const format = (s) => {
    
    let string = '';

    for (let c of s) {

        if (c.match(/[A-Z]/)) string += ' ';

        string += c;
    }

    return string;
};

console.log(format(s));
```

Or alternatively with reduce function:

```js
const s = 'thisIsThisTuesday Day';

const format = (s) => s.split('').reduce((acc, c) => c.match(/[A-Z]/) ? acc + ` ${c}` : acc + c, '');

console.log(format(s));
```