# How to pick only Capital characters from the string?

Tags: javascript

I am try to pick capital characters from the string with the help of a function and for loop but i can't figure out how i can do it i try using toUpperCase as you see it in the code but it is not work any idea how i can do it ?

```
function onlyCapitalLetters(cap){
    var string = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < cap.length; i++){
        if(cap[i] === cap.toUpperCase()){
            string += cap[i];
        }
    }
    return string;
}

onlyCapitalLetters("Apple");
```

Comment: check the ascii value of it for the range of capital letters.

Comment: Typo? it should be `if(cap[i] === cap[i].toUpperCase()){`

Comment: You just need to change `cap[i] === cap.toUpperCase()` to `cap[i] === cap[i].toUpperCase()`

Comment: May be a duplicate of - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055152/finding-uppercase-characters-within-a-string

Comment: Have you considered using a simple regex?`"Only Capital Letters".match(/[A-Z]/g) // ["O", "C", "L"]`

Comment: `cap[i] === cap.toUpperCase()` -- this is one cause for not working. It compares one character to the uppercase version of the entire string. Change it to compare the character with the uppercase version of the same character.

Comment: anyone mind telling me simple way rather than advanced regex thing ?

Comment: try `"BUTTerfly".replace(/[^A-Z]/g, "");`

Answer (score 5):

You can try the regex, with [`String.prototype.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to return capital letters only:

```js
function onlyCapitalLetters(cap){
    return  cap.match(/[A-Z]/g, "").join(''); // join the array to return a string
}

console.log(onlyCapitalLetters("Apple"));
console.log(onlyCapitalLetters("BUTTerfly"));
console.log(onlyCapitalLetters("LION"));
```

Comment: But its the solution right?? ,one of the possible solution may be easy .It doesn't deserves downvote even if it ddeosn't deserves upvote @axiac

Comment: Kindly comment after down vote a answer. it helpful for the user.

Comment: I didn't vote this answer (neither up or down). But it qualifies for a down vote. It is not useful because it does not provide a solution for the question. The function in the question returns a string that contains only uppercase letters. The function suggested by this answer returns a boolean.

Comment: @axiac previously it was returning array ,now with the edit suggested by Dadboz it returns string now

Comment: @Shubh i also noticed that. as per this @axiac you did not run this code ever. but deside its unqualified. his old core is `console.log(onlyCapitalLetters("LION"));`

Answer (score 1):

Can you try like this

```js
function findUpcase(value){
    input = value
    data = ""
    input.split("").map(res => {
        if(res == res.toUpperCase()){
            data = data+ res
        }
    })
    return data
}

console.log( findUpcase("MyNameIsVelu") );
//'MNIV'
```

Comment: Now try. its return string

Comment: Better to use a string throughout instead of joining your array at the end.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comments you need to change `cap.toUpperCase()` to `cap[i].toUpperCase()`.

But you can do it with just one `replace`:

```js
console.log('Apple Orange'.replace(/[^A-Z]/g, ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use `replace` method with Regex to eliminate numbers and letters written in lowercase:

```
let str = 'T1eeeEeeeSssssssTttttt';
let upperCase = str.replace(/[a-z0-1]/g, '')
console.log(upperCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Use Below code to get Capital letter of the sentence :

[Demo Code](https://onecompiler.com/javascript/3yp7k7hhs)

```
var str = 'i am a Web developer Student';
var sL = str.length;
var i = 0;
for (; i < sL; i++) {
    if (str.charAt(i) != " ") {
      if (str.charAt(i) === str.charAt(i).toUpperCase()){
        console.log(str.charAt(i));
        break; 
      }
    }
}
```